# How to loop a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four different button effects where each effect are declared in a variable.

Therefore, I bring all of these four variables and place them within an array called arr in which is used in the `clickByItself()` function using `Math.floor(Math.random())` methods.

Without the `for` loop, the code clicks by itself randomly in one of the four buttons every time I reload the page.

```
function clickByItself() {
   let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
   $(arr[random]).click();
}
```

However, using the `for` loop I am not being able to make these clicks one-by-one within the maximum of 10 times.

```
var blueButtonEffect = code effect here;
var redButtonEffect = code effect here;
var greenButtonEffect = code effect here;
var yellowButtonEffect = code effect here;
var arr = [blueButtonEffect, redButtonEffect, greenButtonEffect, yellowButtonEffect];

//will click on buttons randomly
function clickByItself() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $(arr[random]).click();
        setTimeout(clickByItself(), 1000);
    }
}
```

The final output with the current code above is the four buttons being clicked at the same time, not one-by-one.

So, how can I have this function to press a random button by 10 times one-by-one with one second of interval from each click?

Comment: Why not just create a for loop and go through all of them in order? That way you don't need to rely on luck? Or do you need to be random and not in order?

Comment: I need them to be random. That's why the ```Math.random()``` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your code you need:

1. A base case for your recursion
2. Pass a function reference to setTimeout. Currently, you are executing clickByItself and passing its return value (which is undefined) to setTimeout.
3. Do not use setTimeout in a loop without increasing the time by a factor of i, as the for loop will queue all the function calls at the same time
4. Alternatively, you can use a "times" argument to avoid looping

You could try something like

```
function clickByItself(times = 0) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
  $(arr[random]).click();
  if (++times < 10) {
    setTimeout(function(){clickByItself(times);}, 1000);
  }
}
```

An example with console logs
https://jsfiddle.net/pfsrLwh3/

Comment: they still will be all executed at once. you need to increase the interval for each call to `setTimeout`

Comment: This will not, as the next function won't be queued until the previous one completes https://jsfiddle.net/pfsrLwh3/

Comment: Obrigado @AlbertoRivera.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `for` loop calls the `setTimeout` 10 times very quickly.  If you want to wait until the previous function call finishes prior to calling the next, then you should use recursion or just use a `setInterval`.

Recursion:

```
function clickByItself(numIterations) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    let i;

    $(arr[random]).click();

    if( numIterations < 10 ){
        setTimeout(() => {
            clickByItself(numIterations += 1)
        }, 1000) 
  }      
}

clickByItself(0);
```

With `setInterval`

```
let numIterations = 0;

function clickByItself() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    let i;
    $(arr[random]).click();

    numIterations += 1;

    if( numIterations > 10) {
        clearInterval(loop)
    }
}

let loop = setInterval(test2, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying this is working for only 4 times but I think your above code will run in an infinite loop as you are calling clickByItself() again in the for loop.

If you want press a random button by 10 times one-by-one with one second of interval from each click then replace the for loop with

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      setTimeout($(arr[random]).click(), 1000);
    }
```